# Shopware 6 Plugin - Unable to access the ProductDetailRouteResponse's extension property on Product Detail Page Twig

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6

I'm currently working on a Shopware 6 plugin. I have a `MyCustomProductDetailRoute.php`. My custom file within my plugin's directory sets a variable `$expectedShippingCosts` variable to the extension as follows:

```php
$productDetailResponse->getResult()->addExtension(
                'expectedShippingCosts', $expectedShippingCosts);
```

But when I can not access `expectedShippingCosts` property from the `page.extensions.expectedShippingCosts` in the twig template. My `dump(page)` shows:

```
Shopware\Storefront\Page\Product\ProductPage {#8164 ▼
  #extensions: []
  #header: Shopware\Storefront\Pagelet\Header\HeaderPagelet {#7759 ▶}
  #footer: Shopware\Storefront\Pagelet\Footer\FooterPagelet {#7739 ▶}
  #salesChannelShippingMethods: Shopware\Core\Checkout\Shipping\ShippingMethodCollection {#8083 ▶}
  #salesChannelPaymentMethods: Shopware\Core\Checkout\Payment\PaymentMethodCollection {#8233 ▶}
  #metaInformation: Shopware\Storefront\Page\MetaInformation {#7953 ▶}
  #product: Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\SalesChannelProductEntity {#6490 ▶}
  #cmsPage: null
  #navigationId: "01898d65262070718a76e2a12169ea79"
  #configuratorSettings: Shopware\Core\Content\Property\PropertyGroupCollection {#5563 ▶}
  #reviewLoaderResult: Shopware\Storefront\Page\Product\Review\ReviewLoaderResult {#7964 ▶}
  #selectedOptions: Shopware\Core\Content\Property\Aggregate\PropertyGroupOption\PropertyGroupOptionCollection {#8324 ▶}
  #crossSellings: Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\CrossSelling\CrossSellingElementCollection {#8357 ▶}
}
```

How can I access the extension in the twig template?

Regards,
Lodhi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to

```php
$productDetailResponse->getProduct()->addExtension(
    'expectedShippingCosts', 
    $expectedShippingCosts
);
```

```
{{ dump(page.product.extensions.expectedShippingCosts) }}
```

Comment: I asked a new question related to this. Please have a look.